# Running a cmd command from a pyw file without a window popping out

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

so I am writing a python script that should run constantly in the background and once in a while pings a site to see if my router has failed. 
Anyway, since it's a python script, I am running it as a pyw file, but no matter what way I try calling the ping command, a window always pops out (even if only for a milisecond).
What I've tried so far (and haven't worked):

```
subprocess.call("ping google.com", stdout = IGNORE, stderr = IGNORE)

subprocess.check_output("ping google.com", stdout = IGNORE, stderr = IGNORE)

os.system("ping google.com")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `subprocess.call('cmd /c "start /min ping google.com"')`

Comment: Hey, the window still pops out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you put it in a .pyw script? -- because that doesn't happen on my system. I see an entry in the taskbar for a second, then it goes away.

Comment: Yeah, I've tested that on a different machine, and it is working fine. I  have no idea why a window keeps popping on this one (same OS and same/newer version of python).

Answer (score 0):

you can save ping outputs into file, then print the file content

```
os.system("ping google.com>google.log")
```